# pyserial, ImportError: No module named serial

Tags: python, pyserial

I know this question have been asked several times, but none of the solutions I saw solved my problem.

I have been trying to use the serial library from Sublime Text 2 in my mac.

```
import serial
```

Everytime I call this library, I get this message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/andreapatri/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
      import serial
  ImportError: No module named serial
  [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I already installed python 3

```
brew install python3
```

and pyserial

```
sudo pip install pyserial
```

I am new using mac.
Can you please tell me how to fix the error?

Answer (score 11):

I solved this issue with this:

```
sudo easy_install pyserial
```

Answer (score 10):

This command solved my problem on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install python3-serial
```

Comment: consider `sudo apt ...`

Answer (score 3):

`sudo python3 -m pip install pyserial` did the trick for me on `Mac OSx Catalina 10.15.6`.

Comment: Confirmed big sur 11.2.3

Answer (score 2):

Use python3 for running your script. If you try to use python, you will get this error message.

```
python3 <scriptname>.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python pip:

```
pip install pyserial
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use pip3 instead of pip

pip3[.X] install pyserial

.X is your python3 version

Answer (score 0):

Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```

Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in anaconda command prompt as:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyserial
```

Make sure your relevant serial port is not already used by another program or process that has exclusive access to serial communication.

I hope this helps.